# Are pointers to union required to be aligned for all members

Tags: c, alignment, unions

Given

```
typedef union { unsigned char b; long l; } BYTE_OR_LONG;
```

would it be legitimate to have a function

```
unsigned long get_byte_or_long(BYTE_OR_LONG *it)
{
  if (it->b)
    return it->b;
  else
    return decode_long(it->l); // Platform-dependent method
                               // Could return (it), (it>>8), etc.
}
```

and call it

```
void test()
{
  long l = encode_long(12345678);  // Platform-dependent; could return
                                   // (it<<8), (it & 16777215), etc.
  char b[2] = {12,34};
  BYTE_OR_LONG *bl[3];
  bl[0] = (BYTE_OR_LONG*)&l;
  bl[1] = (BYTE_OR_LONG*)b;
  bl[2] = (BYTE_OR_LONG*)(b+1);
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    printf("%lu\n", get_byte_or_long(bl[i]));
}
```

Certainly constructing an unaligned `BYTE_OR_LONG *p` and then accessing `p->l` would be Undefined Behavior.  Further, even the act of casting an unaligned pointer to `(unsigned long*)` would be Undefined Behavior, since an implementation might not need as many bits for such a type as for a `char*`.  With a union, however, things seem unclear.

From what I understand, a pointer to a union is supposed to be equivalent to a pointer to any of its elements.  Does that mean that implementations required to guarantee that a pointer to a union type must be capable of identifying any instance of any type contained therein [thus a `BYTE_OR_LONG*` would have to be able to identify any `unsigned char`], or are programmers required to only cast to union types pointers which would satisfy every alignment requirement of every constituent therein?

Comment: OT:` It should be `printf("%p\n", (void*) bl[i]);` instead of `printf("%lu\n", bl[i]);`

Comment: @alk: The code was wrong in an important detail--it never passed `bl[i]` to the code that would use it.  Thanks for the comment--I fixed the code above.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean that implementations required to guarantee that a pointer to a union type must be capable of identifying any instance of any type contained therein ... ?

Long question, short answer: Yes.

(I'll dig out the Standard reference later)

Basically it's because a struct/union's 1st element is guaranteed to carry no padding before it.

Comment: If one has a variable `foo` of type `unsigned char*`, then any variable of type `unsigned char*` may have its address taken and stored in `foo`, such that `*foo` would identify that variable. The question is whether, for every variable of type `unsigned char`, a variable of `foo2` of type `BYTE_OR_LONG*` could be made such that `foo2->b` would identify that variable, or if such pointers could only be created for `unsigned char` variables that happened to be at word-aligned addresses.

Comment: I somehow do not seem to understand this issue. `foo2->b` **is** the variable. How would it identify another variable `foo`? @supercat

Comment: Assuming "*such pointers*" refers to pointers typed `BYTE_OR_LONG*`: Yes, its members `b`s would all be aligned like they were typed like `l`, that is `long`s . @supercat

Comment: Ok, I finally got the question. I will delete my answer. @supercat

Comment: Thou shalt not cast wildly. ;-) @supercat

Comment: @supercat: If you'd changed the `12` or the `32` to a `0` your example code would fail miserably.

Comment: I would view calling the function with the 12 or 32 replaced by a zero to be equivalent to calling `printf("%ld",3);` on platforms where `int` and `long` are different sizes.  The whole idea of the union would be that some content that was present within the union would be required to correctly identify what other content was present.

Comment: Where would that `3` come from, please? @supercat

Comment: How about `printf("%ld", someVariableThatWasThoughtToBeLongButActuallyIsnt);`?  My point is that printf receives some information which describes what it kind of variable it should expect to find somewhere; if one tells printf that it's been given a `long`, but it really hasn't, all bets are off.

Comment: Ahok ... the printf will fail, sure, or at least provoke UB. @supercat

Comment: To be precise/refer to your code: For `b == 0` already this line `return decode_long(it->l);` would provoke the UB. @supercat

Comment: My point is that it's accepted to have a method which expects information in a certain format, and which will provoke UB if given improperly-formatted information.  Personally I really *dislike* printf, since the fact that a lot of code which will work when `long double` and `double` are the same size will break if they aren't, has led to compiler developers failing to properly support long double.  On many platforms with *and without* hardware FPU support, 80-bit floats are faster and easier to work with than 64-bit; having arithmetic operands promote to such a type would be useful...

Comment: ...if code which needed to hold temporary intermediate results could do so accurately.  Unfortunately, the fact that a lot of code used `%f` and `%lf` willy-nilly led to compiler writers' adoption of a hack to make all such code work: just alias `long double` to `double`, and don't bother letting programmers store intermediate results accurately.

Comment: Err... at least in the code you show the issue it not with printf, but with `it->l` when having done `char c = 0; BYTE_OR_LONG * it = (BYTE_OR_LONG *) &c;`  before. @supercat

Comment: In the `c==0` case, UB would certainly be invoked by passing C's address to the `get_byte_or_long()` method *if it hadn't been before*.  The question is whether UB would occur when the pointer was dereferenced, or when it was cast to the union type.  By the sound of another answer, it would occur at the cast.

Comment: *mafso*'s answer is correct, I'd say. The key point in the Standard is the "*If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned [...] **for the referenced type**, the behavior is undefined*". In your case the referenced type is the union. Thanks for helping me to understand your question, btw ...

Answer (score 0):

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned [...] for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. [C11 (n1570) 6.3.2.3 p7]

I couldn't find any explicit guarantees about the alignment requirements of unions, so the conversion to the union pointer appears not strictly conforming. On my machine, `_Alignof(char)` is 1, but `_Alignof(BYTE_OR_LONG)` is 4.

> *Does that mean that implementations required to guarantee that a pointer to a union type must be capable of identifying any instance of any type contained therein [thus a `BYTE_OR_LONG*` would have to be able to identify any unsigned char], or are programmers required to only cast to union types pointers which would satisfy every alignment requirement of every constituent therein?*

No, a pointer to `T` may be made point to any union containing a `T`, not necessarily the other way round. As far as I know, the alignment requirements of a union could even be stricter than those of all of its members.

Comment: I would expect that `_Alignof(someUnion)` would report an alignment which would allow every member of the union to be used.  The question is essentially whether one may legitimately create a pointer of union type which satisfies the alignment requirements of some but not all members, if only members whose alignment requirements are met are ever accessed.

Comment: @supercat: As I said, the alignment requirements are violated as soon as a pointer is converted to one wrongly aligned for its target. It doesn't matter whether you dereference it or not. If you want to assume a platform where pointers to unaligned addresses aren't a problem (but accesses through such a pointer are), the code is defined, I think.

Comment: ... though it technically still would violate strict aliasing (or maybe not), but that's a currently open issue in the C11 standard afaik.

Comment: I thought that was likely, though I was curious if there's anything in the standard which clarifies.  Conceptually, if a method accepts a pointer which must be aligned if it points to one kind of data, but need not be aligned if it points to a different type, it would seem nice to have it accept a pointer type which could convey that message to the programmer, but if the standard doesn't allow that then accepting a byte-alignable type would seem better.

Comment: I can see some interesting issues with strict aliasing too.  As a common real-world scenario, given `typedef union {uint8_t bb[4]; uint32_t l;} QUAD;`, would a compiler be required to assume that if the address of a `uint32_t` may have been cast to `QUAD*`, a method which accepts a `QUAD*` may affect the `uint32_t`?  Scenarios of the latter type would seem pretty common.

Comment: I think I see what your question is getting at, and how and when this could be useful, but don't think the standard gives such a guarantee. I searched the C11 draft for "align" and "union", but couldn't find any guarantees. And the behavior is explicitly undefined for wrongly aligned pointers as per my quote (and at least with C11, alignment requirements can be inspected, and on my platform, your union has stricter requirements than a `char`), and to my understanding of standardeese, explicit undefinedness is stronger than explicit definedness, so even if we find something, that wouldn't help.

Comment: This question about aliasing is roughly what the current standard committee discussion (and a few defect reports) try to address. We can discuss and try to summarize the current state of the discussion in chat and put that into a Q&A (I'm missing something like that here on SO currently, especially trying to get the intent of the committee) if your in the mood of reading defect reports and committee discussions. But I think it's out of the scope of this question. BTW, is this a language-lawyer question or a question about what works on common implementations? Could make a big difference here.

Comment: I'd be up for a chat at some point.  One of my current interests is in a part-theoretical-part-practical design for a string-passing paradigm which would be safer than unbounded-length zero-terminated strings--something where one could write something like `MSTRING(16384) buff; STR_INIT(buff);`, with the former declaration allocating about 16388 bytes on the stack, one could then say `concat(buff, string1); concat(buff, string2); concat(buff, string3);` and have `buff` contain the first 16384 characters of the combined string (possibly setting an error flag).

Comment: I'd further like to support `concat(buff, tmidst(string4, 100, 250));` and have it concatenate up to 250 characters from string4, starting at index 100, *without having to make a copy of the text in question*, and have reduced overhead for shorter strings, all while being able to identify any kind of string with a single pointer.  I think that should be doable if one says that a pointer to a number 0-63 identifies a 0-63 character string stored after it, and pointers to other byte values identify other kinds of things, some with alignment requirements and some not.

Comment: @supercat: For your general problem: Is there anything wrong with using plain `char *` everywhere and just cast to `long *` if you know it actually points to one? A cast to `char *` is always fine (including the indirection). If you want your "strings" to have their own type, you can use a `struct { char c; }` instead. I guess most compilers wouldn't put padding there, and even if they do, this doesn't necessarily affect alignment requirements, the former implies the latter and can be statically asserted, and in C11, the latter can be statically asserted directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72856/discussion-between-supercat-and-mafso).

Comment: @supercat: Now I'm online ;)